# Consider supporting Programming Language Design and Implementation on Area 51!

Tags: discussion

Interested in designing or implementing programming languages, including golfing languages? Or have strong opinions about either? Consider supporting **[Programming Language Design and Implementation](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/127456/programming-language-design-and-implementation)**, a proposed Stack Exchange site, over on Area 51 (Stack Exchange's proposal system for new sites)!

Follow [these](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32774/if-you-are-showing-a-rep-of-51-or-151-you-may-have-committed-incorrectly-make-s/32776#32776) instructions to properly link your account, Area 51 can be really weird sometimes. (Just ignore the step telling you to follow Solana, and follow PLDI instead :p)

Once you commit, when we hit private beta in a month or two, you'll be able to participate (you don't have to though, despite the name).

Comment: I feel like this is too soon of off the question about whether this is allowed especially when considering the vote ratios on that.

Comment: It's been three days and the answer in favor of it being allowed is at +9. It's got more than twice as many upvotes as downvotes. I think it's pretty unlikely that changes any time soon.

Comment: Remember not to hit "log in" like I did, took me a few days to figure out my mistake. So if you see two Jacobs on the A51 proposal, that's why

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms Exactly it's only been *3 days* and the top answer has *7 downvotes*.  Even if it had no downvotes I would not consider 3 days ample time.